# How to show that the set {$a.b$ :$a \in A,b\in B$} is closed sei in $\mathbb R^n$ where $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a compact set in $\mathbb R$$ -${$0$} and $B$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$ then how to show that the set {$a.b$ :$a \in A,b\in B$} is closed sei in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a_nb_n \in AB$ converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $(a_n) \subset A$ implies that there is a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k} \to a$, where $a\neq 0$. Then
$$
b_{n_k} \to x/a
$$
whence $x/a \in B$ and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_nb_n$ converge to $x$. Then some subsequence of $a_n$ converges to $a \ne 0$. Show that the corresponding subsequence of $b_n$ converges to $x/a$.